# How to select this DIV in my website html?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image]

As you can see in the image how I can select highlighted div element in css? I have div with w-grid-item-h in other block of the page so I cant use it directly to change the css. This is the output of my wordpress theme so I can't assign it desired class name!

Comment: 1- Try posting code instead of an image,
2- In your browser, you can see below the `selector` used to highlight the div.

Comment: You are clearly using a UI library that provides some CSS classes to style their components. For you to make any manual changes, or selecting specific elements within their template, you'll need to give custom classes or other identifiers, to parent elements containing this div. Question is too general and will be really hard to give a specific answer to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the closest parent with an ID (which should be unique) and traverse down to your target element

```
#us_grid_2 > .w-grid-list > article > .w-grid-item-h {
  color: #f00;
}
```

you can use the simpler approach and let the browser search all descendants on its own if you know there won't be any other elements matching the same hierarchy

```
#us_grid_2 .w-grid-item-h {
  color: #ff0;
}
```

Comment: if `us_grid_2` is auto generated, the next time he changes the layout in his template, that ID might be auto generated into a different name, which might break this CSS rule...

Answer (score 1):

If that div is so special just give it an id and use that id in your CSS.

```html
<div class="w-grid-item-h" id="my-very-special-div"></div>
```

```css
#my-very-special-div {
  color: pink;
}
```

Comment: That is, if he has direct access to those DOM elements. Sometimes they are being rendered in run-time by template generators, and he cannot modify them in HTML.

Comment: Can that be solved with an extra class instead of id?

Comment: The issue is not the type of CSS selector he should be using, but whether he can change the HTML to begin with. If this template is auto generated in DOM in run-time using some UI framework (like Vue / React / Angular), it could be tricky to implement this. What you see in the DOM is not always the same template you feed the browser :)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. But I don't know that it's actually hard to manipulate the output HTML using the templating engine...

Comment: Given that we are the ones generating the HTML obviously!

Comment: Sometimes we are not the ones generating the template, but 3rd party UI libraries... And since I don't have enough information in the question, I cannot assume anything...

Answer (score 0):

We need the whole document to ensure the selector is unique.  I would start by selecting by the class `.w-grid-item-h`.  This might select the divs in each of your articles.  If you only want the first one then go up the tree (possible till you find a parent with a suitable id) and use :first-child, :first-of-type, etc.  Your data-id attribute might be useful here too. `article[data-id=182] div` Also if you have control of the server side, don't overlook the option of generating a suitable id attribute.